# How can I get rid of white/blank areas in a ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a ListDensityPlot of a list of points bayesianRiskList with entries {k, h, b}. In building it, I iterate over {k, 0, 1, 0.01} and {h, 0, 5000, 50}, thus calculating a particular b(k,h):

```
Do[
minBR = {{-1, -1}, +Infinity};
  Do[
   br = costs[[k*100 + 1]] + h *(1 - accuracies[[k*100 + 1]][[2]]);
   AppendTo[bayesianRiskList, {k, h, br}];
   If[br < minBR[[2]], minBR = {{k, h}, br}]
   , {k, 0, 1, 0.01}];
  AppendTo[minimumBRList, minBR[[1]]];
  AppendTo[minimumBRValuesList, minBR[[2]]];
  , {h, 0, 5000, 50}];
ListDensityPlot[bayesianRiskList, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 Axes -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Bayesian Risk - " <> name <> " - za=" <> ToString[N[za]], 
   32], FrameLabel -> {Style["k", 32], Style["h", 32]}, 
 ImageSize -> Full, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> 
  ListPlot[minimumBRList, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize -> Small}, 
    PlotRange -> All][[1]]]
```

The result is the following color map:
[image: broken color map]

I get blank areas, as if there were no values for that area, even though they are present in the list. I can tell this by just printing the values of the list in those areas, so I know I build the list correctly. Moreover, this does not happen when I use a smaller range for h, such as {h, 0, 1000, 10}.
I have already seen some posts about this happening, but all the answers basically converge to saying that you just need to add `PlotRange->All` and `ClippingStyle->Auto`, which I already have added to my function.

Comment: You did not specify some functions or variables e.g., cost. This prevents us from trying your code to help you. Please post all definitions. One piece of advice right away:  This:  `costs[[k*100 + 1]]` is incorrect, since k is rational, while the variable in the double bracket is always integer. The second advice: avoid `Do` as much as possible. Use `Table` instead.

Comment: thank you for the advice. costs is a list of 101 rational numbers, accuracies is a list of two rational numbers (e.g. {a, k}). k*100+1 converts from the range [0, 1, 0.01] to [1, 100], so the number in the double bracket is always an integer. Why should I avoid Do? I'm not a pro with Mathematica, but I've read the manual and it seemed as a useful iteration function.

Comment: **1**. "costs is a list of 101 rational numbers..." People here expect you give all necessary definitions in an explicit form. Then we can evaluate your code and see what's wrong with it.  If you do not provide us with the necessary information easy to access to, we will hardly spend time in delving into your problem.  **2.** "k*100+1 converts from the range [0, 1, 0.01] to [1, 100], so the number in the double bracket is always an integer." This is not right in Mathematica. Have a look in Documentation.

Comment: Continuation: **3**. "Why should I avoid Do?" It is general knowledge that Do is better to avoid in Mathematica. Except for a few very rare cases, Table makes all the job faster and requires a more concise code.